# Navigating to a specific div from an external link

Tags: javascript, html, href

I'm trying to make a certain link that redirects the user to a certain div within the page.
(e.g `https://blabla.github.io/my-website`)

My code is pretty simple and it works locally:

```
<div id='projects'>
      <h1 className='pt-32 text-5xl pb-10 text-center font-gloria italic'>
        Some of my projects <span className='text-xs '>(so far...)</span>
      </h1>
</div>
```

when I try to link to :
`https://blabla.github.io/my-website#projects`
It does redirects me the page yet not to the specific div I need.

would appreciate the help!

Comment: Then you might have more than one id="projects" or the div is at the end of the page

Comment: Assuming you don't have anything else with that ID, the anchors will need the page to have enough content/space under the div to push it up to the top.

Comment: it's the only id whos using the projects tag and there's enough space as far i set it.
also,i assume if there wasn't it wouldn't work on localhost but i'm not really sure.

Answer (score 0):

To navigate to a specific div on a page from an external link, you can use a technique called "fragment linking." This involves adding a # followed by the id of the div you want to link to, at the end of the URL. For example, if the URL of the page is https://www.example.com and the id of the div you want to link to is my-div, the link would be https://www.example.com#my-div. When someone clicks on this link, they will be taken to the page and automatically scrolled to the div with the id of my-div.

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="my-div">
      This is the div I want to link to.
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

To create a link to this div, you could use the following HTML:

```html
<a href="https://www.example.com#my-div">Click here to go to the div on the page</a>
```

When someone clicks on this link, they will be taken to the page and automatically scrolled to the div with the id of my-div.

Comment: Hello, i'm not using any href inside the code, the link i'm providing is just a link i try to set on a pdf